# Despeckling documents - OCR

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, filter, ocr

I have searched but i can't find an algorithm to do despeckling in a scanned document. I have already used Median filter to remove some smaller speckles.

I need an algorithm that removes large speckles from a document, I have tried using Connected Component Labeling (using Aforge) but there is no option to color an object white (remove it) if it is larger than X pixels.

Is there any way to delete objects on my picture that are larger than X pixels (specks, blobs, noise)?

Edit:

Here is the document which I am trying to prepare for OCR. 
[Original Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZouy.jpg)

As we can se there is a lot of noise on the left of the text. So then I use Blur to blur the noise on the left, and then I Binarized the document and got something like this [After Binarization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWFEC.png)

Now I need to remove the large black area from the left. I just dont know how to do that...

Comment: Have you tried using tesseract?

Comment: Could you please post a picture or a link to a picture? For an image processing question, assume you should always post a sample image. Even if you see many different kinds of speckle/noise in your document, having a few sample images will help those trying to give you advice. There are quite a few ways to eliminate blobs/speckle, but different techniques will be chosen depending on the types of noise you typically see.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have edited the question and added some more info and images. I have not tried using tesseract, I am trying to implement all the algorithms myself...

Comment: Is cropping the image an option? i.e. find the area of black and crop to the inside edge of it

Answer (score 0):

Just a try in Matlab.

```
img = imread('xWFEC.png');
img = imcomplement(imclearborder(imcomplement(img)));
figure; imshow(img);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Want to add an explanation of how this works, especially as this is a `C#` question and as far as I know those functions, or similar, are not available in standard `C#` and so would need to be implemented by the user themselves.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, Thanks again. As far as I know we can use 'EmguCV' (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) with C#. This SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters) clearly explains how to implement Matlab 'imclearborder' with OpenCV.