# Improve Text Binarization / OCR Preprocessing with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, threshold

I am building a scanner feature for my app and binarize the photo of the document with OpenCV:

```
    // convert to greyscale
    cv::Mat converted, blurred, blackAndWhite;
    converted = cv::Mat(inputMatrix.rows, inputMatrix.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cv::cvtColor(inputMatrix, converted, CV_BGR2GRAY );

    // remove noise
    cv::GaussianBlur(converted, blurred, cvSize(3,3), 0);

    // adaptive threshold
    cv::adaptiveThreshold(blackAndWhite, blackAndWhite, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 15 , 9);
```

The result is okay, but scans from different scanner apps are much better. Especially very small, tiny sized text is much better:
Processed with opencv
[image: First: my result]

Scanned With DropBox
[image: Second: Scanned with dropbox]

What can I do, to improve my result?

Comment: Your result doesn't look like a binary image (characters have some fading), or is it the jpg compression when saving the image?

Comment: hm yeah thats actually true, it really seems as the image below (the result, what I want to achieve) does contain more than 2 colors. So maybe, applying an adaptive threshold might be the complete wrong approach?

Comment: Applying a threshold must result in a binary image. Check that your image is binary and save it in a non-loss format so you can actually see what your real result looks like. Then you can also apply some morphology to clean up a little bit the result.

Comment: Can you share the original image ? I would like to try processing it on my machine.

Comment: sure, I uploaded a similar image with the processed versions of opencv and a scanner app here: http://imgur.com/a/e0UZk

Comment: Not sure how dropbox does do it (didnt knew they did), but their pre processing add details that are not in your original image looking at 7th word umlaut on a, such details are not in your original, so thats not a simple filter, probaply some neural network trying to improve the text first. But how to know all the font types ?.. i guess only big parties could afford it, or maybe train it on the text itself to identify all characters.

Comment: May be you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731810/segmenting-license-plate-characters/24732434#24732434)

Comment: Did you find any reliable solution for your data set?

Answer (score 3):

May be the apps are using [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) to make their binarized output look nicer. To obtain a similar effect, I first tried binarizing the image, but the result didn't look very nice with all the jagged edges. Then I applied pyramid upsampling and then downsampling to the result, and the output was better.

I didn't use adaptive thresholding however. I segmented the text-like regions and processed those regions only, then pasted them to form the final images. It is a kind of local thresholding using the Otsu method or the k-means (using combinations of `thr_roi_otsu`, `thr_roi_kmeans` and `proc_parts` in the code). Below are some results.

Apply Otsu threshold to all text regions, then upsample followed by downsample:

Some text:

[image: otsu1txt]

Full image:

[image: otsu1x]

Upsample input image, apply Otsu threshold to individual text regions, downsample the result:

Some text:

[image: otsuparts2xtext]

Full image:

[image: otsuparts2x]

```
/*
apply Otsu threshold to the region in mask
*/
Mat thr_roi_otsu(Mat& mask, Mat& im)
{
    Mat bw = Mat::ones(im.size(), CV_8U) * 255;

    vector<unsigned char> pixels(countNonZero(mask));
    int index = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; c++)
        {
            if (mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
            {
                pixels[index++] = im.at<unsigned char>(r, c);
            }
        }
    }
    // threshold pixels
    threshold(pixels, pixels, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    // paste pixels
    index = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; c++)
        {
            if (mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
            {
                bw.at<unsigned char>(r, c) = pixels[index++];
            }
        }
    }

    return bw;
}

/*
apply k-means to the region in mask
*/
Mat thr_roi_kmeans(Mat& mask, Mat& im)
{
    Mat bw = Mat::ones(im.size(), CV_8U) * 255;

    vector<float> pixels(countNonZero(mask));
    int index = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; c++)
        {
            if (mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
            {
                pixels[index++] = (float)im.at<unsigned char>(r, c);
            }
        }
    }
    // cluster pixels by gray level
    int k = 2;
    Mat data(pixels.size(), 1, CV_32FC1, &pixels[0]);
    vector<float> centers;
    vector<int> labels(countNonZero(mask));
    kmeans(data, k, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), k, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
    // examine cluster centers to see which pixels are dark
    int label0 = centers[0] > centers[1] ? 1 : 0;
    // paste pixels
    index = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; c++)
        {
            if (mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
            {
                bw.at<unsigned char>(r, c) = labels[index++] != label0 ? 255 : 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return bw;
}

/*
apply procfn to each connected component in the mask, 
then paste the results to form the final image
*/
Mat proc_parts(Mat& mask, Mat& im, Mat (procfn)(Mat&, Mat&))
{
    Mat tmp = mask.clone();
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(tmp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    Mat byparts = Mat::ones(im.size(), CV_8U) * 255;

    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
    {
        Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        Mat msk = mask(rect);
        Mat img = im(rect);
        // process the rect
        Mat roi = procfn(msk, img);
        // paste it to the final image
        roi.copyTo(byparts(rect));
    }

    return byparts;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat im = imread("1.jpg", 0);
    // detect text regions
    Mat morph;
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    morphologyEx(im, morph, CV_MOP_GRADIENT, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 1);
    // prepare a mask for text regions
    Mat bw;
    threshold(morph, bw, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    morphologyEx(bw, bw, CV_MOP_DILATE, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 10);

    Mat bw2x, im2x;
    pyrUp(bw, bw2x);
    pyrUp(im, im2x);

    // apply Otsu threshold to all text regions, then upsample followed by downsample
    Mat otsu1x = thr_roi_otsu(bw, im);
    pyrUp(otsu1x, otsu1x);
    pyrDown(otsu1x, otsu1x);

    // apply k-means to all text regions, then upsample followed by downsample
    Mat kmeans1x = thr_roi_kmeans(bw, im);
    pyrUp(kmeans1x, kmeans1x);
    pyrDown(kmeans1x, kmeans1x);

    // upsample input image, apply Otsu threshold to all text regions, downsample the result
    Mat otsu2x = thr_roi_otsu(bw2x, im2x);
    pyrDown(otsu2x, otsu2x);

    // upsample input image, apply k-means to all text regions, downsample the result
    Mat kmeans2x = thr_roi_kmeans(bw2x, im2x);
    pyrDown(kmeans2x, kmeans2x);

    // apply Otsu threshold to individual text regions, then upsample followed by downsample
    Mat otsuparts1x = proc_parts(bw, im, thr_roi_otsu);
    pyrUp(otsuparts1x, otsuparts1x);
    pyrDown(otsuparts1x, otsuparts1x);

    // apply k-means to individual text regions, then upsample followed by downsample
    Mat kmeansparts1x = proc_parts(bw, im, thr_roi_kmeans);
    pyrUp(kmeansparts1x, kmeansparts1x);
    pyrDown(kmeansparts1x, kmeansparts1x);

    // upsample input image, apply Otsu threshold to individual text regions, downsample the result
    Mat otsuparts2x = proc_parts(bw2x, im2x, thr_roi_otsu);
    pyrDown(otsuparts2x, otsuparts2x);

    // upsample input image, apply k-means to individual text regions, downsample the result
    Mat kmeansparts2x = proc_parts(bw2x, im2x, thr_roi_kmeans);
    pyrDown(kmeansparts2x, kmeansparts2x);

    return 0;
}
```