# After cropping a image, how to find new bounding box coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr, image-preprocessing

Here's a receipt image that I've got and I've plotted it using matplotlib,

```
# x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4
bbox_coords = [[650, 850], [1040, 850], [1040, 930], [650, 930]]

image = cv2.imread(IMG_FILE)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
ax.imshow(gray, cmap='Greys_r'); 
rect = Polygon(bbox_coords, fill=False, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r')
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()

print(gray.shape)
(4376, 2885)
```

[image: receipt image]

Then, I've cropped the original gray image and plotted it again with same bounding box coordinates and here's the result,

```
# cropped the original image    
gray_new = gray[25:4314, 147:2880] 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
ax.imshow(gray_new, cmap='Greys_r'); 
rect = Polygon(bbox_coords, fill=False, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r')
ax.add_patch(rect)
plt.show()

print(gray_new.shape)
(4289, 2733)
```

[image: cropped receipt]

So, I'm looking for a way to make **bounding box to fit the cropped image**. I couldn't figure out how I can achieve it.

Edit:

Here's an another image if you want to replicate the question, [`receipt-2`](https://ibb.co/9nTbrVD) and these are the b-box coordinates for the image `[1638,1462,2974,1462,2974,1549,1638,1549]`.

Comment: if you cropped 25 pixels on the left then substract 25 pixels from all `X` values. Similar for top crop and `Y` values.

Comment: @furas I've cropped `25:4314` so what about 4314 on the right side?

Comment: it doesn't matter how many pixels you croped on right and bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cropped `25` pixels on the left and `147` pixels on the top then you have to substract `25` pixels from all `X` values and `147` pixels from `Y` values 
because all elemenets on image moved 25 pixel to the left and 147 pixels to the top.

```
box_coords = [
    [650-25,  850-147],
    [1040-25, 850-147],
    [1040-25, 930-147],
    [650-25,  930-147]
]

print(bbox_coords)
```

**EDIT:** Using code

```
bbox_coords = [[650, 850], [1040, 850], [1040, 930], [650, 930]]

bbox_coords = [[x-25, y-147] for x,y in bbox_coords]

print(bbox_coords)
```

**BTW:** and it doesn't matter how many pixels you cropped on right and bottom.

---

**EDIT:** Calculation for rescaling image

Calculate size which keep proportions

```
old_width = 4376
old_height = 2885
new_width = 550
#new_height = 270 # doesn't keep proportion
new_height = int(new_width/(old_width/old_height)) # keep proportion

print('new size:', new_width, new_height)
print('proportions:', (old_width/old_height), (new_width/new_height))

new_image = resize(original_img, shape=(new_width, new_height))
```

Calculate position when image change size (I assume that it doesn't keep proportions).

```
scale_x = old_width/new_width
scale_y = old_height/new_height

print('scale:', scale_x, scale_y)

bbox_coords = [[int(x/scale_x), int(y/scale_y)] for x,y in bbox_coords]

print(bbox_coords)
```

If image keeps propotion then `scale_x == scale_y` and you can calculate and use only one scale for all values.

Comment: Thank you :) ..Actually for me, x-147, and y-25 is giving me the correct bounding box like the below answer. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just one more similar doubt that I have, here I have manually cropped the result but in my project I'm also resizing the image like `resize(original_img, shape=(550, 270))` here the resize functions automatically converts `(4376, 2885)` to `(550, 270)` then how can I find the new bounding box values?

Comment: first: you don't keep aspect ration `(4376/2885, 550/270)` gives `(1.5, 2.0)` so you deform page. It should have height `550/(4376/2885)` which gives `362`. Second: you have to calculate scales `scale_x = 4376/550`, `scale_y = 2885/270` (gives `sx=7.95, sy=10.68`) and you divide all `X` by `scale_x` and all `Y` by `scale_y`.

Comment: I added calculations to answer.

Comment: I tried the solution but it's giving me wrong bounding boxes.

Comment: did you use `new_height = 270` if you resized to `(550, 270)` ?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. I got it now. I calculated it with cropped height and weight. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the coordinates of the Polygon, the same quantity that you cropped in `x` and in `y` coordinates.

Take into account that when you apply `gray_new = gray[25:4314, 147:2880]`, this means `[rows, columns]`, so for the plot, you are removing the first 25 pixels on `y` axis and the first 147 pixels on `x` axis.

The results would be

```
bbox_coords = [[x - 147, y-25] for x, y in bbox_coords]
```

and in values:

```
bbox_coords = [[503, 825], [893, 825], [893, 925], [503, 925]]
```