# Shrink the bounding boxes in an Image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

I have an image(Image.size = (328, 231)) of a table and the bounding boxes of text on that image stored in a dictionary.

[image: Image of the Table]

The contents of the dictionary are

```
{"bounding_boxes": [{"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 0.0, 53.94900093453785, 18.455579291781646]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 0.0, 184.96800320412976, 51.735807141009545]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 0.0, 256.199368074407, 51.735807141009545]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 0.0, 328.0, 51.735807141009545]}, {"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 18.455579291781646, 53.94900093453785, 76.14130756377666]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 51.735807141009545, 184.96800320412976, 76.14130756377666]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 51.735807141009545, 256.199368074407, 76.14130756377666]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 51.735807141009545, 328.0, 76.14130756377666]}, {"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 76.14130756377666, 53.94900093453785, 105.33448988766077]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 76.14130756377666, 184.96800320412976, 115.66887643031575]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 76.14130756377666, 256.199368074407, 115.66887643031575]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 76.14130756377666, 328.0, 115.66887643031575]}, {"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 105.33448988766077, 53.94900093453785, 146.28279243942194]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 115.66887643031575, 184.96800320412976, 146.28279243942194]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 115.66887643031575, 256.199368074407, 146.28279243942194]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 115.66887643031575, 328.0, 146.28279243942194]}, {"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 146.28279243942194, 53.94900093453785, 175.9430656804882]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 146.28279243942194, 184.96800320412976, 201.86661158409726]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 146.28279243942194, 256.199368074407, 201.86661158409726]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 146.28279243942194, 328.0, 201.86661158409726]}, {"class": "text", "box": [0.0, 175.9430656804882, 53.94900093453785, 231.0]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 201.86661158409726, 184.96800320412976, 219.67445280166658]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 201.86661158409726, 256.199368074407, 219.67445280166658]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 201.86661158409726, 328.0, 219.67445280166658]}, {"class": "text", "box": [53.94900093453785, 219.67445280166658, 184.96800320412976, 231.0]}, {"class": "text", "box": [184.96800320412976, 219.67445280166658, 256.199368074407, 231.0]}, {"class": "text", "box": [256.199368074407, 219.67445280166658, 328.0, 231.0]}]}
```

After plotting the bounding boxes in the given JSON data, the image looks like so,
[image: Image of the table plotted with bounding boxes]

But, I want to shrink these boxes so that they cover the text tightly, like in the image below

[image]

I have tried cv2.boundingRect() with some image thresholding but didn't succeed. (source [How to remove extra whitespace from image in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636344/how-to-remove-extra-whitespace-from-image-in-opencv))

```
data = <<The dictionary from above>>
new_boxes = list()
img = cv2.imread('sam.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8)
for item in data["bounding_boxes"]:
    xmin = int(item['box'][0])
    ymin = int(item['box'][1])
    xmax = int(item['box'][2])
    ymax = int(item['box'][3])
    crop_img = gray[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    coords = cv2.findNonZero(crop_img)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
    new_box = [x, y, w+x, h+y]
    new_boxes.append(new_box)
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean that you have tried cv2.boundingRect() after finding the contours ?

Comment: I sliced the bounding box from image array

img = cv2.imread('sam.png')   
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8)   
crop_img = gray[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]   
coords = cv2.findNonZero(crop_img)   
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords) 
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636344/how-to-remove-extra-whitespace-from-image-in-opencv

Comment: In your above code I don't see how are you using your dictionary of bounding boxes to slice your original image into smaller images. Is this slicing step done, and done correctly?

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: You have added that you have tried "cv2.boundingRect() with some image thresholding but didn't succeed." Could you please give details about how it did not succeed? Was there an error? Was the bounding boxes too small or too big?