# How to process an image for Tesseract?

Tags: python, image, ocr, tesseract, image-segmentation

I am trying to read characters from a low resolution image using Tesseract:

[image]

Using indications from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034214/4986615), I tried adaptive thresholding, but results are not convincing

[[image: adapt thresholding]]

I also tried to adapt code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24732434/4986615) without more success.

Would you have any idea to improve pre-processing?

Comment: Honestly I think it is too low res, but at least the image needs to be straightened horizontally, and the border has to go.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have any idea to help to rectify the skew? Hough lines detector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented an OCR using Keras and CTC loss function. Results are great!

You can find details of the OCR on the [Keras github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) and explanations about the method [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-connectionist-temporal-classification-3797e43a86c).